# Why does this trig addition equal what it does?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $\frac{3\pi}2+\frac \pi 2 = 2 \pi$? Where does the $3$ go?

Comment: Well, if it's $\frac{3 \pi}{2}+\frac{ \pi}{2}$, you can re-write it as $\frac{3 \pi + \pi}{2}$ and simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\frac {3\pi}2 + \frac \pi 2 = \frac 12 (3\pi + \pi) = \frac 12 (3\pi + 1\pi) = \frac 12 (4\pi) = \frac {\cancelto {2}{4} \pi} {\cancel 2} = \frac {2\pi} 1 = 2\pi$$

Comment: Wow, I did not think about that 1 beside that pie.

Answer (score 1):

> *where does the three go?*

The three goes into the four.

Comment: What four? there is not a four.

Comment: @user184726: If there is no four, then where did the two come from ?

Comment: Catchy, but probably a more detailed explanation is suited here.